# Goldstein's proof that $W = -\Delta V$: Why is $\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

On page 11 of the third edition of Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics*, the book claims that

> If the difference vector $\textbf{r}_i - \textbf{r}_j$ is denoted by $\textbf{r}_{ij}$, and $\nabla_{ij}$ stands for the gradient with respect to $\textbf{r}_{ij}$, then $$\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij}V_{ij} = -\nabla_j V_{ij}$$...

I understand why $\nabla_i V_{ij} = -\nabla_j V_{ij}$, but I don't understand why $\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij}$. My vector calculus is less than ideal apparently. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the potential $V_{ij}$ depends on the difference ${\bf x}_{ij} = {\bf x}_i - {\bf x}_j$, so

$$
\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_j} = 
\frac{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_j} \frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}
= \frac{\partial ({\bf x}_i - {\bf x}_j)}{\partial {\bf x}_j} \frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}} = 
-\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}
$$

Similarly

$$
\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_i} = +\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}
$$

Or in Goldstein's notation

$$
\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij} = -\nabla_j V_{ij}
$$

Comment: Please explain what $\partial/\partial \textbf{x}$ means in terms of the components of $\textbf{x}$.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy It is the gradient $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial {\bf x}} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_1}\hat{\bf e}_1 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_2}\hat{\bf e}_2 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_3}\hat{\bf e}_3$$